# Datamapper validations, empty errors

Tags: validation, datamapper

I have a simple model with the following properties:

```
property :title, String,
  :required => true,
  :length => 1..200

property :body, String,
  :required => true,
  :length => 1..200
```

When I save it (using the save method) with an title that doesn't validate, it won't save, but I get the follow object:

```
<DataMapper::Validations::ValidationErrors:0x00000003133e10
 @resource=#<Pun @id=nil @image="" @title="" @body="dsfsdf" @description=nil
 @published=nil @user_id=1 @round_id=nil>, @errors={}>
```

So the errors hash is empty. However, when it's the body property that's empty, the errors hash detect its problem.

Any idea on why the errors hash is empty when it involves the :title property?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So [knowtheory](https://github.com/knowtheory) wrote in a comment on a [blog](http://www.drmaciver.com/2010/04/datamapper-is-inherently-broken/) (in 2010)
that some helper methods were created to compensate for this. His examples for a User model:

`User.raise_on_save_failure = true` - for all user instances to blow up.

`DataMapper.raise_on_save_failure = true`
 - for EVERYTHING to blow up if it doesn’t save successfully.

Source definitions: [dm-core/model.rb](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/model.rb#L88) and [dm-core/resource.rb](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/master/lib/dm-core/resource.rb#L1238)